# List population

Tags: python, list

```
i = int(input('enter number of input: '))
for a in range (0, i):
    listInput = int (input("enter your list numbers: "))
    List1 = []
    List1.append(listInput)
    
print(List1)
```

the list only populates the second iteration number not the first input.

Comment: You re-assigning a new empty list to `List1` during each iteration. If you only want to make `List1` an empty list once, move `List1 = []` to outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

include the `List1` outside the for loop cuz its getting reinitialized everytime.

Do You want to let user add numbers in a list?
If so, I got a different code snippet

```py
n = int(input("enter number of input: "))
a = list(map(int,input("Enter your list numbers : ").split()))[:n]
```

Comment: I have to disagree with "better" here. First, this behaves differently than OP's code (taking input on one line rather than several). Second, I have to stare at this for a minute and figure out what it's doing, whereas with OP's code I can tell instantly what the flow of the program is. Shorter is not necessarily better. Code is written once and read many times, so we should optimize for the reader.

Comment: changed it 
thanks for that information btw